# ¿Se pueden agregar sub-carpetas en el directorio drawable de proyectos android?

Tags: android

En un proyecto android, si tengo una gran cantidad de imágenes dentro del directorio drawables ¿Las puedo organizar en sub-carpetas?

Ejemplo de una estructura de directorios:

```
drawable/*.png
drawable/deporte/*.png
drawable/finanzas/*.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente con Android Studio puedes crear subfolders pero el compilador no los toma en cuenta y los excluye, de hecho no se incluyen en el archivo `R.java` .

Lo que se realiza es agregar sufijos o prefijos en los nombres de recursos, por ejemplo:

```
drawable/miimagen_deporte.png
drawable/miimagen_finanzas.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Para efectos de organización si puedes colocarlos en subdirectorios, te entiendo, porque cuando uno tiene una cantidad considerable de drawables, el solo abrir la carpeta en Android Studio da miedo!! pero al momento del código no te detecta los subdirectorios, debes usar sufijos.